# NSMutabledictionary not working

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I am new to Iphone programming. Please correct me where am I going wrong.

I have two viewcontrollers

```
viewcontroller1 viewcontroller2
```

In viewcontroller1,

```
-(IBAction) getQuestions:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"In get questions..");

    [[self viewcontroller2] initWithData:userInfo];

    [self presentModalViewController:viewcontroller2 animated:YES];

    [quesions autorelease];
}
```

In viewController2 I have the following code.

```
    -(id)initWithData:(NSMutableDictionary*)data
    {   
        self = [super init];

        if(self)
        {
        userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:data];
        }

        return self;
    }



 -(IBAction) getQuesionAfterPopUp:(id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"In get question..After popup...%@",userInfo);

}
```

For some reason "userInfo" is null. Why is it null even after using init with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't initialize correctly, therefore the instance variable `userInfo` is not accessible.

Initialization should look like this:

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSMutableDictionary *)data 
{
    self = [super init]; // 'self' and it's instance variables are accessible at this point ...
    if (self) 
    {
        userInfo = // etc...
    }
    return self;
}
```

You might want to [read up on this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW17) for more information on how to implement designated initializers. Especially focus on the topic **Implementing an Initializer**.

Comment: thanks for your time. But unfortunately that did not fix the issue.

Comment: By the way, are you sure you want to alloc and initialize a new dictionary with your existing dictionary? Wouldn't it be a better idea to just copy the object? E.g.: `userInfo = [data mutableCopy];`? Did you check if data is actually not nil before you assign it to userInfo? Might it be a good idea to make `userInfo` a property instead of just an instance variable?

Answer (score 0):

in the above code you don't retain your `userInfo` object. Try

```
userInfo = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:data]]retain];
```

Or if userInfo is a property like:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)
```

Try:

```
self.userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:data]];
```

Which will automatically retain the userInfo. Please note by not calling self you are assigning straight to the instance variable.

Finally, make sure that the `data` object is not empty